# Troubles shutdown selenium webdriver with protractor webdriver-manager

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

i'm attempting to upgrade protractor from version  4.0.14 to 5.0.0 with latest standalone selenium server + latest IE driver, and facing issue that on sending shutdown command via webdriver-manager, nothing happens, i still see process up and running.

Here more detailed info on environment:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Node.JS 6.9.1
- NPM 3.10.8
- Protractor Package 5.0.0
- Webdriver-manager status gives this

  - [15:26:20] I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.0.1 [last]
  - [15:26:20] I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.26 [default] [last]
  - [15:26:20] I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.12.0 [default] [last]
  - [15:26:20] I/status - IEDriverServer version available: Win32_3.0.0 [last]
  - [15:26:20] I/status - android-sdk is not present
  - [15:26:20] I/status - appium is not present
- tests are running on IE 11
- webdriver started with Protractor webdriver-manager script with those parameters:

  - --detach
  - --quiet
  - --started-signifier
  - --versions.standalone=3.0.1
  - --versions.ie=3.0.0
- All processes started and finished throw Gulp

Webdriver-manager shutdown command prints this:
[15:10:57] I/shutdown - Attempting to shut down selenium nicely

But i still can see Java processes hosting Webdriver ...

Any idea what that could be ? Sounds as a bug

Comment: Detaching then sending the command to shutdown does not currently work with the latest webdriver-manager noted in the https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/199. This is because the following API (/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer) was removed from selenium-standalone server v3.0.1. This used to work in selenium standalone server v2.53.x.

No fix is out for this yet.

Comment: Whoa, that's done on purpose seems .... Even that i do not see reasoning for it. Thank you for pointing out issue number.

Comment: On webdriver-manager side of things, we could write the process id and then kill that id as the shutdown command. I just don't think there is bandwidth to make it a feature.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a command to kill the process listening on port 4444 (selenium server)

```
cmd /V /C "echo off && set "killed=0" && (for /F "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr ":4444"') do if not %a == 0 if not !killed! == 1 (taskkill /F /PID %a && set "killed=1")) || echo No webdriver process found"
```